# How to exclude a string with RegEx in Google Analytics?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Is there any other way (other than using custom segments) I can make a 1:1 comparison between the traffic of two **subsets** of pages, where one is `directory1` (ie. `^/directory1/(.*)`) and the other is `everything but directory1` using RegEx in Google Analytics?

I know negative lookahead is not allowed in GA. Any doable workaround?

I'd like to obtain a similar stacked chart where the blu line represents `directory1` and the orange one `everything but directory1`:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with Google Analytics [custom Content Groups](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en) or custom dimensions. You can just do a custom report and set include to contentGroup1 and exclude to contentGroup2

Comment: not what I needed. i needed a way of doing this with regex. I know it can be done in many other ways.